# React Native fetch won't work with redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to make a simple fetch call, to a backend that I wrote myself in NodeJS. Although, I am having a hard time getting the fetch to work. I am using Redux Thunk together with Redux in React Native to sort out states and props, in order to make a self navigating login / register view. My actions look something like this:

**actions.js**

```
import {
    LOGIN,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAILED
} from '../constants/constants'

export function loginAPI() {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(userLogin())
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('json:', json)
        dispatch(userLoginSuccess(json.success))
      })
      .catch(err => dispatch(userLoginFailed(err)))
    }
  }

function userLogin() {
    return {
        type: LOGIN,
    }
}

function userLoginSuccess(token) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        token,
    }
}

function userLoginFailed() {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILED,
    }
}
```

**user.js (*reducer*)**

```
import {
    LOGIN,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAILED,
    } from '../constants/constants'

const initialState = {
    token: "",
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}

export default function reducers(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN:
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: true,
            token: ""
          }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            token: action.token
          }
        case LOGIN_FAILED:
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            error: true
          }
        default:
          return state
      }
}
```

and finally, this is my rendering page.

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableHighlight, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { loginAPI } from '../actions/actions'

let styles

const Login = (props) => {
  const {
    container,
    text,
    button,
    buttonText
  } = styles

  const { token, isFetching } = props.user;
  console.log('Token: ', props.token);

  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <Text style={text}>Redux Example</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight style={button} onPress={() => props.loginAPI()}>
        <Text style={buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      {
        isFetching && <Text>Loading</Text>
      }
      {
        token ? (<Text>Name: {token}</Text>) : null
      }
    </View>
  )
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 100,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#0b7eff'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white'
  }
})

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    loginAPI: () => dispatch(loginAPI())
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login)
```

issue here is that the fetch call never seems to make it to the backend. I have a log going on the backend to tell when a call is made to the API, and it never shows up. Debugging, checking the state shows that success (token) is null, which is understandable since the call is never made. The route to users returns a JSON object which contains a value "success", which is true. How come my loginAPI isn't fetching?

And lastly this is my configStore

**configStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import app from '../reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(app, applyMiddleware(thunk))
  return store
}
```

Comment: Do you have a GET /users on your API? Usually, most developers do a POST on the API with username and password and get a token. You seem to do a GET.

Comment: yeah it's one I made as a test. The rest require hashed info to get a token from, so thought it would be easier to do this way. It returns {success: true}

Comment: Could it be because the server is hosted locally? Are there some restrictions when using fetch that you can only call https DNS's?

Comment: Yeah, possible that is because it is localhost. localhost may point to the emulator or device itself. You can try with the private IP if you are on the same network.

Comment: Fixed it. Fortforwarding 2995 - 3005, and changing content to JSON when doing a post call fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortforwarding from 2995 - 3005 both UDP / TCP fixed the issue, aswell as using my IPv4 address instead of localhost.